Retrieving the Query String of a GET Request Sent to an AWS API Gateway to SQS Queue
I'm trying to send a GET request to an Amazon API Gateway and retrieve the query string to SQS queue. I've successfully done this with the POST method, but I'm struggling with the GET method and keep getting 403 responses.
Here's what I've tried so far using Terraform configuration
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "webhook" {
  name        =  "webhook-api"
  description = "POST to SQS queue"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "this" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.webhook.id
  parent_id            = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.webhook.root_resource_id
  path_part            = "somepath"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "get" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.webhook.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.this.id
  api_key_required     = false
  http_method          = "GET"
  authorization        = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "get" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.webhook.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.this.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.get.http_method
  type                    = "AWS"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  passthrough_behavior    = "NEVER"
  credentials             = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_webhook_role.arn
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:sqs:path/myqueue"

  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = "Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$util.urlEncode($input.params().querystring)"
  }

}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "get_response_200" {
  rest_api_id       =  aws_api_gateway_rest_api.webhook.id
  resource_id       =  aws_api_gateway_resource.this.id
  http_method       =  aws_api_gateway_method.get.http_method
  status_code       =  aws_api_gateway_method_response.get_response_200.status_code
  selection_pattern = "^2[0-9][0-9]"  // regex pattern for any 200 message that comes back from SQS

  response_templates = {
    "application/json" = "{\"message\": \"OK!\"}"
  }

  depends_on = [ aws_api_gateway_integration.get ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "get_response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.webhook.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.this.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.get.http_method
  status_code = 200

  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "this" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.webhook.id
  stage_name  = "v1"

  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.get
  ]

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
      aws_api_gateway_integration.get.id
    ]))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

The response (Postman, trying https://evnhfwnej3.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/somepath?value=1234):
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H1>403 ERROR</H1>
    <H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
    <HR noshade size="1px">
    Bad request.
    We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a
    configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
    <BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
    <BR clear="all">
    <HR noshade size="1px">
    <PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: 3ofZT3meC1o6shJePaKFdgkqK9KOPY7s97W4_P02OV43HQnRHfFUTQ==
</PRE>
    <ADDRESS>
    </ADDRESS>
</BODY>

</HTML>

Does anyone know how to properly modify Terraform configuration to get this working? Thanks in advance.
